# check if number is rang or not while creating call by asterisk call file

Tags: asterisk, voip, phone-call, ivr, pbx

I am creating call through call file. The asterisk cli shows different staus for a call like `hangup` and `remote end ringing`. **I just want to get the status if that number is rang or not. Is there any way I can do that?** I am generating call from call file and it should be missed so there is no dialplan code I can write because the dialplan I write would only execute when user picks the call which is not in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asterisk AMI interface events to see result

You also can call via Local/ channel,that way it will go via dialplan and check DIALSTATUS variable

But i highly not recommend you do dialling core without enought experience. Use already created one like vicidial.org.

Answer (score 0):

Create callfile like this :

**PHP Script**

```
<?php

$callfile = "";
$callfile .= "Channel: Local/123@outbound_test\n";
$callfile .= "Context: out\n";
$callfile .= "Extension: 100\n";
$callfile .= "Set: dialout_number=9876543210\n";

$callfilename = "callfile_".uniqid();

file_put_contents(__DIR__."/".$callfilename, $callfile);
chmod(__DIR__."/".$callfilename, 0777);
exec("mv ".__DIR__."/$callfilename /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing");

?>
```

In **/etc/asterisk/extensions_custom.conf** ::

```
[outbound_test]
exten => 123,1,Noop(Dialout number ${dialout_number})
exten => 123,2,Dial(SIP/outbound-trunk/${dialout_number})
exten => 123,3,Noop(Dial status  for ${dialout_number} is ${DIALSTATUS})

[out]
exten => 100,1,Noop(Answered)
exten => 100,n,Hangup
```

In **outbound-test** **line 3** you will get dial status except Answer. If Answered, **out** context will start executed. Possible dial status are :

1) **BUSY** : called number is busy. Dial reached the callee

2) **NOANSWER** : Number rang for too long and dial time out reached

3) **CONGESTION** : Congestion. This status is usually a sign that the dialled number is not recognised

4) **CHANUNAVAIL** : Channel unavailable. On SIP, peer may not be registered.

5) **DONTCALL** : Privacy mode, callee rejected the call

6) **TORTURE** : Privacy mode, callee chose to send caller to torture menu

Comment: Ive tried the your solution with call file directly but it dint work cli shows congestion circuit busy for Local channel do I need to configure anything to use this Local channel.

Comment: Did you setuped outbound trunk properly?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ${REASON}.
I use ${REASON} in my dialplan to get to know if .call file failed or answered, If call is answered it goes to the main flow if its failed it goes to "failed extension"

`exten => failed,1,Noop(##No Answer##=> ${REASON})
exten => failed,n,Set(__CALLFAILED=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)})`

> The ${REASON} variable is set by Asterisk when it enters the special Failed extension. It seems to give the only ways of finding out why a call file call failed. It takes at least these values:
>
> 0 - Failed (not busy or congested)
>   1 - Hung up
>   3 - Ring timeout
>   5 - Busy
>   8 - Congestion

Comment: thanks your answer really helped me.But I have some issue.I am using call file with waittime 5 sec in call file and if I test this on switched off phone the output is `3`(Ring timeout) which is not correct and if I test call file with same condition but waittime 20 sec the `${REASON}` gives me `1`. It would be a great if you can help?

Comment: I would say don't use waittime set it to default 0, Because every telecom provider have their own call connect time and if you use less wait time call is not completely connected or use higher waittime. Most of the telecom companies have 60 sec for ring timeout